# ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT in js fetch

Tags: javascript

I use the following code to access the response:

```
var url_to_geotiff_file = "http://127.0.0.1:8009/files/1.tif";
fetch(url_to_geotiff_file).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
    })
```

But these codes return the following error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8009/media/1.tif net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

How can I fix this error?